# SQL query for an unpopular product

Tags: mysql, sql

Trying to calculate the most unpopular product in MySQL 5.7, I run the following query:

```
SELECT
    ClientOrderItem.ItemId AS ID_product,
    countIf(Orders.ClientOrderStateID = 3) AS cnt
FROM
    ClientOrderItem
    LEFT JOIN Orders ON ClientOrderItem.ClientOrderID = Orders.id
    LEFT JOIN AdditionalInfo ON ClientOrderItem.ClientOrderID = AdditionalInfo.ClientOrderID
WHERE
    Orders.ClientOrderStateID = 3
    AND (
        AdditionalInfo.code = 'IsTestOrder'
        AND AdditionalInfo.value = '0'
    )
GROUP BY   cnt
ORDER BY   cnt DESC;
```

I get the following error:

> SQL Error [1305] [42000]: FUNCTION ozon.countIf does not exist

Can you tell me what to replace the "countIf" function with?
Thanks.

Comment: The error message is quite clear: there is no function countif() in MySql.

Comment: Tell me, in the 8 version of MySQL, the countif() function is supported?

Comment: Not in any version of MySql.

Comment: How then can I rewrite the request so that the condition is met (Orders.ClientOrderStateID = 3)?

Comment: Edit your question and explain what you want to do. Also post sample data of all tables involved and expected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not explain what you mean by "most unpopular".  However, in MySQL, if you want to count the rows where `Orders.ClientOrderStateID = 3`, then you can use

```
sum(Orders.ClientOrderStateID = 3) AS cnt
```

The more standard syntax is:

```
sum(case when Orders.ClientOrderStateID = 3 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
```

Comment: Thank you, both options give the desired result!

Answer (score 1):

as mentioned in the comment mysql doesn;t support 'countif'
you can follow this syntax:

```
SELECT
    ClientOrderItem.ItemId AS ID_product,
    count(IF Orders.ClientOrderStateID = 3,1,NULL) AS cnt
FROM
 ...
```

OR

```
SELECT
    ClientOrderItem.ItemId AS ID_product,
    count(case when Orders.ClientOrderStateID = 3 then 1 end) AS cnt
FROM
 ...
```